# How to show the weight of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, phtml

I use the file: app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml

```
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
     <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get like that

```
    <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
         <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
    </span>
    <span>
<?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
        <?php echo  $pro->getWeight(); ?><?php echo $this->__('gram');?></span>
```

Comment: Please write where to insert this line?

Comment: done now add it and feedback..

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens...:-( I added code in price.phtml.

Comment: update answer kindly check..

Comment: Checked, unfortunately, nothing has changed...:-(

Comment: kindly check you are editing the correct file enable template hint from admin panel and check..

Comment: I am using the theme RWD. Correct file enable template hint from admin panel and check. Сorrects file price.phtml

Comment: did it show the the gram text?..

Comment: updated the answer kindly check and update. this is tested and showing product weight.